# Duffing equation in real world

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm having a hard time to find a scenario in physics (or in any science) where I can meet the duffing equation with all coefficients not zero (the most general case)

The equation is $x''+\delta x'+\alpha x+\beta x^3=\gamma \cos(\omega t)$

for example I read on wikipedia that I can modelize a "pendulum with a spring that doesn't exactly obey the Hooke's law", but what would the comeback force be then?

Of course, any help/hint would be really appreciate.

Thanks, have a good day.

Comment: The comeback force is $-\alpha/m x- \beta/m x^3$.

Comment: How is this phenomenum called, in literature? If you know

Comment: I'm not sure who studies these things, but this is just a first-order correction to Hooke's law for a symmetric restoring force. In general, if you have a symmetric restoring force that is a function of displacement, you can Taylor expand it; the first term gives you Hooke's law, the even terms are zero due to symmetry, and the next order correction is the $x^3$ term.

Comment: @stochastic:  wouldn't the comeback force be $-\alpha m x - \beta m x$?  Then it corresponds to the inertial force $mx''$.

Comment: You are right, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a student of physics, the real question should not be, "Why is $\beta \ne 0$?" but rather "Why *should* we take $\beta = 0$?".  Most "springs" don't really obey Hooke's law; elastic deformation isn't really linear.  The second order term vanishes near equilibrium because it is a local minimum of the potential energy, so after the linear term, the cubic term in the potential force is the most significant in general.

Physicists like the approximation $\beta = 0$ because the resulting linear equation is explicitly solvable, and because it is reasonably accurate in many cases.  However, if we measure the forces more accurately, we often see the $\beta \ne 0$ term.

Mathematicians, however, like to take $\beta \ne 0$, because otherwise the linear system is ***too easy to solve***.  Also, the phenonomena associated with this nonlinearity include fun stuff like chaos.

Note that the pendulum equation without linearization is

$\ddot \theta + \mu \dot \theta + \lambda \sin \theta = 0; \tag 1$

also,

$\sin \theta = \theta - \dfrac{\theta^3}{6} + \ldots, \tag 2$

so to third order in $\theta$ the force "looks like" that of a spring with a cubic correction term, a spring which "doesn't exactly obey Hooke's law"; in the case of (2), the "comeback force" is apparently $-\lambda \sin \theta$; to third order in $\theta$ this is $-\lambda \theta - \lambda \theta^3 / 6$

But hell, even some physicists like chaos.  Reminds me of my desk . . .